# Wiring a 2 pole circuit

Tags: electrical

Can I use a #8 and a #6 wire for a 40 amp circuit?I know individually the size is fine,just not sure about mixing them a#8 for one leg and #6 for the other

Comment: Attempting to use up wire scraps?

Comment: I'm not a licensed electrician, so this is not an answer. As you noted, the wire gauges both meet code for 40 amps, assuming copper conductors (according to my reference, #8 supports at least 40 amps and up to 55 depending on conductor/insulation type, while #6 supports at least 55 amps). The circuit breaker provides your over-current protection, and the larger diameter wire might be cooler than the smaller, but otherwise there's no difference. *BUT* this application might not meet your local code, and it won't meet the national code unless you have correct insulation color.

Comment: (actually, different conductors might not meet the national code either, but I didn't see anything about that after quick look in my reference book, and there are rules in there for conductors that don't have an external sheath).

Comment: What color are these wires, and what type are they?  Also, what size raceway are you pulling through?

Answer (score 1):

Each circuit has a minimum wire size.

Other than that, you can **upsize wires anytime you want**.   There's no restriction.

The wires must, of course, fit the terminations.  So if you use #12 Romex to branch off a 15A circuit, you will not be using backstsbs on that receptacle.

To reverse it, if your circuit is almost entirely #12, but has one bit of #14, it is a 15A circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague. Let's say you are using a #6 for a 120V 20A circuit and a #8 for a neutral, and a #8 is adequate to carry your load. Then it is perfectly fine to use the wires as you have described. However, if you are using a #8 and a #6 as a 240V 40A circuit. This creates an imbalance of the load and causes all kinds of different problems. First an imbalance of a load and an impedance problem causing overheating and improper operation of the load of the equipment you are using.

I don't think there is an exact NEC code for a branch wire, but Article 310.10(H) (even though it covers parallel feeders) does try to explain the engineering reason why it would not be prudent to do what your are trying. It's one of those things that is covered in an Engineering or Electrician training classes.

Comment: "This creates an imbalance of the load" - I don't think that's true.  If a significant fraction of the load is in the conductors there is something badly wrong.  If a #8 (finer) wire doesn't present too much resistance, then a #6 (thicker) wire will present even less resistance, and half of effectively nothing is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running individual conductors you have to be in conduit.
You didn't mention an equipment grounding conductor, so now your conduit has to be metal that's properly installed to be the equipment ground.
If all else is right and the circuit is sized for the smaller conductor, I'd say you're good to go.